# Merge two hashes with arrays by the same key Ruby

Tags: arrays, ruby, hash

I need some help with Ruby. I have two hashes parsed from JSON. I use this code to parse files:

```
document = JSON.load File.new("hosts.txt")
file = JSON.load File.new("admins.txt")
```

The result are two big hashes like that:

```
document={"total"=>13, "subtotal"=>13, "page"=>1, "per_page"=>20,
          "search"=>nil, "sort"=>{"by"=>nil, "order"=>nil},
          "results"=>[
             {"ip"=>"10", "environment_id"=>7, 
                 "medium_id"=>nil, "name"=>"one", "id"=>1},
             {"ip"=>"15", "environment_id"=>7, 
                 "medium_id"=>nil, "name"=>"two", "id"=>1},
             {"ip"=>"10.5", "environment_id"=>6, 
                 "medium_id"=>nil, "name"=>"four", "id"=>1}]}

file={"admins"=>[
           {"name"=>"one", "surname"=>"Mark", "email"=>"mark@o.com"},
           {"name"=>"two", "surname"=>"Adam", "email"=>"Adam@o.com"},
           {"name"=>"four", "surname"=>"Ami", "email"=>"Ami@o.com"}]}
```

From the first hash I need only information from the results key, so I have done

```
data = document["results"]
```

I've done the same for the second hash:

```
people = file["admins"]
```

Now, when the **"name"** values are the same I want to move surname and email from the people array to data array and have another hash like this:

```
new = {"all_data"=>[
        {"ip"=>"10", "environment_id"=>7, "medium_id"=>nil,
           "name"=>"one", "id"=>1, "surname"=>"Mark", "email"=>"mark@o.com"},
        {"ip"=>"15", "environment_id"=>7, "medium_id"=>nil,
           "name"=>"two", "id"=>1, "surname"=>"Adam", "email"=>"Adam@o.com"},
        {"ip"=>"10.5", "environment_id"=>6, "medium_id"=>nil,
           "name"=>"four", "id"=>1, "surname"=>"Ami", "email"=>"Ami@o.com"}]}
```

Can you help me to do that and explain how it works?

Answer (score 1):

```
personal_data = file['admins'].map(&:dup)
                              .group_by { |e| e.delete('name') }
```

the `dup` / `delete` trick above is not necessary, since `merge` below will be handled properly in any case, but it’s here for the sake of semantic clarity.

```
document['results'].map do |h|
  h.merge(personal_data[h['name']].first) if personal_data[h['name']]
end

#⇒ [
#    {"ip"=>"10", "environment_id"=>7, "medium_id"=>nil, "name"=>"one",
#       "id"=>1, "surname"=>"Mark", "email"=>"mark@o.com"},
#    {"ip"=>"15", "environment_id"=>7, "medium_id"=>nil, "name"=>"two",
#       "id"=>1, "surname"=>"Adam", "email"=>"Adam@o.com"},
#    {"ip"=>"10.5", "environment_id"=>6, "medium_id"=>nil, "name"=>"four",
#       "id"=>1, "surname"=>"Ami", "email"=>"Ami@o.com"}]
```

Comment: Thanks, but I get an error:
test.rb:14:in `block in <main>': undefined method `first' for nil:NilClass (NoMethodError)
        from test.rb:13:in `map' 
        from test.rb:13:in `<main>'   so what is wrong?

Comment: I could suggest that `file['admins']` might lack the presence of the `name` specified in the `results`. You should’ve mentioned this in the question, since on your test data provided everything works like a charm. Please see an updated version.

Comment: Thank You, it works :) But could You explain me that code step by step?
What means &:dup in personal_data = file['admins'].map(&:dup)? What do You group when the 'name' item is deleted?

Comment: `personal_data` is the hash built with [`Hash#group_by`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.3/Enumerable.html#method-i-group_by) from your input `file['admins']`. Print it out to see how it’s organized. On the second action we iterate the `document['results']` hash and merge it’s entries against previously build `name ⇒ details` hash. I doubt I could explain it clearer than the original code does.

Comment: `e.delete('name')` can be confusing. The method not only removes the item from the collection but also returns the deleted item, which fact is used in the code. The deletion operation itself is not necessary here but, as long as  @mudasobwa chosen to mutate a copy of the source data, it allows for easily tracing the data flow on each iteration step.